# How to fix Hover css effect tremble/shaking?

Tags: html, css

```css
 .head .nav li + .box {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(234, 236, 244, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 100%);
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 89%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
}

.head .nav li:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(6, 11, 101, 1) 50%, rgba(66, 12, 119, 1) 100%);
}

.head .nav li:hover + .box {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    min-height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.head .nav li:hover + .special {
    min-height: 240px;
}

.head .nav li:hover p {
    color: var(--whiteColor);
}

.head .nav li + .box .logo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -22px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .multiple {
    top: 15px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .logo img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #0f0b68;
}

.head .nav li + .box .steps {
    min-width: 300px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .steps .top {
    padding: 10px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .steps .top div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .steps .top div img {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .steps .top div p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .steps .bottom {
    border-style: dotted;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: var(--vintageGray);
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 150px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .steps .bottom div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .steps .bottom div img {
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
}

.head .nav li + .box .steps div p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
    color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="pt pt1 active" data-cont="r1">
                                <p>إصدار رخصة استثمار للمستثمر الأجنبي</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>على المستثمر إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_2.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt2" data-cont="r2">
                                <p>إصدار سجل تجاري</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>على المستثمر إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>يجب القيام بالتالي قبل الانتقال للخطوة القادمة</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_1.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt3" data-cont="r3">
                                <p>التسجيل مع الجهات الحكومية</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box special">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>على المستثمر إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>يجب القيام بالتالي قبل الانتقال للخطوة القادمة</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo multiple">
                                    <img src="images/logo-almawared.png" alt="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_10.png" alt="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_11.png" alt="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_9.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt4" data-cont="r4">
                                <p>التعاقد مع مكتب هندسي </p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>على المستثمر إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>يجب القيام بالتالي قبل الانتقال للخطوة القادمة</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt5" data-cont="r5">
                                <p>الحصول على إقرار مساحي </p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>على المستثمر إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt6" data-cont="r6">
                                <p> الحصول على رخصة بناء</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_3.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt7" data-cont="r7">
                                <p>توصيل الماء والكهرباء إلى
                                    المبنى (٪٧٥ من اكتمال المبنى)</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo multiple">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_4.png">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_5.png">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt8" data-cont="r8">
                                <p>الحصول على رخصة إتمام البناء - شهادة الإشغال</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_3.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt9" data-cont="r9">
                                <p>تقديم طلب ترخيص منشأة </p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>على المستثمر إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_6.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt10" data-cont="r10">
                                <p>استلام المخاطبات</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_6.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt11" data-cont="r11">
                                <p>المعاينة الميدانية للكشف على
                                    سلامة المبنى</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_7.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt12" data-cont="r12">
                                <p>الحصول على رخصة مزاولة
                                    نشاط تجاري وشهادة السلامة</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box ">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo multiple">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_7.png" alt="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_3.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt13" data-cont="r13">
                                <p>التسجيل في نظام شموس
                                    وإصدار الرقم المرجعي</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_8.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt14" data-cont="r14">
                                <p>تقديم خطاب إثبات الربط مع شموس</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>يام 5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_6.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt15" data-cont="r15">
                                <p>تفعيل حساب المنشأة في
                                    منصة الرصد السياحي</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_6.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt16" data-cont="r16">
                                <p>المعاينة الميدانية للكشف على جاهزية المبنى</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_6.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt17" data-cont="r17">
                                <p>سداد الرسوم وإصدار الترخيص</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_6.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt18" data-cont="r18">
                                <p>تفعيل اشتراك المنشأة في نظام شموس</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_8.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt19" data-cont="r19">
                                <p>تأييد التأشيرات والحصول على
                                    الموافقة</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/thumbnail_6.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt20" data-cont="r20">
                                <p>استخراج تأشيرات للكوادر</p>
                            </li>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="steps">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>على المستثمر إنشاء حساب جديد في حال عدم وجوده</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء مؤتمت</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>اجراء يتطلب الدفع</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/logo-almawared.png" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li class="pt pt21" data-cont="r21">
                                <p>بدء النشاط</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="line">
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[kindly check how the hover tremble / shake](https://mhmd2991.github.io/saudiproject/iwaainfo.html)

```
.container .iwaainfo .progrss .head .nav li + .box {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(234, 236, 244, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 100%);
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 89%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
}

.container .iwaainfo .progrss .head .nav li:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(6, 11, 101, 1) 50%, rgba(66, 12, 119, 1) 100%);
}

.container .iwaainfo .progrss .head .nav li:hover + .box {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    min-height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

please check the link the see how the hover tremble / shake especial when the scroll is in the end
below the css code i use the `visibilty hidden` to remove the box with `opacity 0` and `max-height 0` on hover the `opacity 1` `visibilty visible` and `min-height 150px` so why sometime the box is tremble / shake especialy when the scroll is in the bottom of the page how can i fix that please?

The tremble appear if you hover on the li when the scroll is in the bottom and when you hover you scroll more down if you rehover again the problem appear

Comment: @j08691 thank you for your reply i did it

Comment: @user3018000 Add a transition time to your hover effect. EX: `transition: all 2s ease-in-out;`

Comment: @Kameron thank you for your reply i did but this doesn't fix the problem and the problem doesn't appear every time sometimes appear specialy whe the scroll is in the bottom

Comment: @Kameron The tremble appear if you hover on the li when the scroll is in the bottom and when you hover you scroll more down if you rehover again the problem appear